# What is the equivalent of ufw in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, firewall, ufw

Trying to connect to Digital Ocean from a Windows 10 computer and getting Connection timed out on port 22. I learned it is because the port is blocked and needs to be opened. This command `sudo ufw allow 22` opens it in Linux. What is the similar command to open it in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has its own firewall, and it can be used to open port 22 for SSH connections. However, much like on GNU/Linux machines, you need some SSH server software to actually listen for and to facilitate these connections.

There is no default SSH server software that comes bundled with a Windows 10 install, but you can easily enable it as an optional feature.

- `Settings > Apps > Apps and Features > Manage Optional Features`
- To install the OpenSSH server, locate "OpenSSH Server", then click "Install".
- *Installing OpenSSH Server using this method will create and enable a firewall rule named "OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP". This allows inbound SSH traffic on port 22.*

However, the 'ufw equivalent' PowerShell command to open this port for the OpenSSH daemon is:
`New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22`

For more details on the steps I provided and steps to do all of the installation via PowerShell, you can visit the [official Microsoft OpenSSH documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Comment: The answer provided by @Reece M is close but addresses cases when you are running a SSH server locally and expecting connections coming in - which is not the case here. The command seen in the documentation could still be adapted to your needs:

`New-NetFirewallRule -Name ssh-client -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Client (Outbound)' -Enabled True -Direction Outbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -RemotePort 22`